# Imported data only showing in first column in JTable (Java)

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I tried to make a simple GUI where I can add the First/Last Name of a person and their date of birth. After adding the data to the JTable I can save it in a TxT File and Load it back into the JTable again.

Part where Data is saved:

```
private void saveListener(){
    jb1.addActionListener(e -> {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        int returnVal = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(PeopleGUI.this);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {     // Datei Explorer
            try {
                File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                PrintWriter o = new PrintWriter(file); // o steht für Output

                for (int col = 0; col < peopleModel.getColumnCount(); col++) {
                    o.print(peopleModel.getColumnName(col) + ";");
                }

                o.println("");

                for (int row = 0; row < peopleModel.getRowCount(); row++) {
                    for (int col = 0; col < peopleModel.getColumnCount(); col++) {
                        o.println(peopleModel.getValueAt(row, col));
                    }
                }

                o.close();
                // Output in der Konsole
                System.out.println("Success!");
            } catch (IOException c) {
                c.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Part where Data is loaded:

```
public void loadListener() {
    jb2.addActionListener(e -> {
    final JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    int response = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(PeopleGUI.this);
    if (response == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("jlist.txt"));

            // Erste Linie sind Kolonnen Beschriftungen
            String firstLine = br.readLine().trim();
            String[] columnsName = firstLine.split(";");
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) peopleList.getModel();
            model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnsName);

            // Daten vom TxT holen
            Object[] tableLines = br.lines().toArray();

            // Reihen mit Daten
            for (int i = 0; i < tableLines.length; i++) {
                String line = tableLines[i].toString().trim();
                String[] dataRow = line.split("/");
                model.addRow(dataRow);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException b) {
                b.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is, that the imported data is only showing in the first row:

[This is how it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS7V5.png)

Does anyone now how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you save your data to a file

```
for (int row = 0; row < peopleModel.getRowCount(); row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < peopleModel.getColumnCount(); col++) {
        o.println(peopleModel.getValueAt(row, col));
    }
}
```

Here you save each cell of the JTable in a new line. You want to save each row in a new line with values separated by /

```
for (int row = 0; row < peopleModel.getRowCount(); row++) {
    String r = "";
    for (int col = 0; col < peopleModel.getColumnCount(); col++) {
        r += peopleModel.getValueAt(row, col);
        if (col < peopleModel.getColumnCount() - 1) {
            r += "/";
        }
    }
    o.println(r);
}
```

EDIT: As @camickr stated use StringJoiner is better

```
for (int row = 0; row < peopleModel.getRowCount(); row++) {
    StringJoiner stringJoiner = new StringJoiner("/");
    for (int col = 0; col < peopleModel.getColumnCount(); col++) {
        stringJoiner.add(peopleModel.getValueAt(row, col).toString());
    }
    o.println(stringJoiner.toString());
}
```

Comment: (1+) for the basic solution, but instead of using String concatenation I would suggest you can use a `StringJoiner` to build the line of data.